# Install Rmpi on Centos fails with "can't find -lmpi"

Tags: r, linker, cluster-computing, mpi

I have mpi running on a cluster. It works fine for executables, as well as C programs; so I am pretty sure it works fine. However, when I am trying to install Rmpi, I get an error.

**Architecture:**

- Centos 6.4
- [MPICH](http://www.mpich.org/downloads/) 3.0.3 (had the same problem with 1.4).
- R 2.15
- [Rmpi](http://www.stats.uwo.ca/faculty/yu/Rmpi/) 0.6-3

I tried different combinations. Specifically, tried to run install.packages() from inside R, and R CMD INSTALL from command line. I tried sudo, su -, and even install into non-privileged "private" directory (in case setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH screws things up). So, here is an example of what I ran:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/tmp/shared/mpich2-install/lib/
install.packages("Rmpi", configure.args = c("--with-Rmpi-include=/opt/tmp/shared/mpich2-install/include/", "--with-Rmpi-libpath=/opt/tmp/shared/mpich2-install/lib/", "--with-Rmpi-type=OPENMPI", "--with-mpi=/opt/tmp/shared/mpich2-install/"))
```

In every event I get consistent error:

```
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/local/lib64 -o Rmpi.so RegQuery.o Rmpi.o conversion.o internal.o -L/opt/tmp/shared/mpich2-install/lib/ -lmpi -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lR
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmpi
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Note, that if I put mpi-type as MPICH (instead of OPENMPI) I get an error about bad format.

I ran out of ideas... There is a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13570873/installing-rmpi-on-lam-mpi-cluster) post, but my problem seems different. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this is a known incompatibility between MPICH and Rmpi. I installed Open MPI and everything worked just fine. Maybe, it will help somebody as well...