# Installing Rmpi on Centos6 'can't find -lmpi'

Tags: r, centos, mpi

Hey I have seen the following two questions here:

1. [Install Rmpi on Centos fails with "can't find -lmpi"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16175891/install-rmpi-on-centos-fails-with-cant-find-lmpi)
2. [Installing Rmpi on LAM/MPI cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13570873/installing-rmpi-on-lam-mpi-cluster)

But they don't provide any concrete answer to the problem.

The following is some pertinent information:

```
R> system('echo "$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"')
/usr/lib64/R/lib:/usr/local/lib64:/usr/lib/jvm/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java/lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/lib64/openmpi/lib

R> install.packages("Rmpi", configure.args="--with-Rmpi-include=/usr/include/openmpi-x86_64 --with-Rmpi-libpath=/usr/lib64/openmpi --with-Rmpi-type=OPENMPI")
```

This is the last part of the error message:

```
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/local/lib64 -o Rmpi.so RegQuery.o Rmpi.o conversion.o internal.o -L/usr/lib64/openmpi -lmpi -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lR
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmpi
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Rmpi.so] Error 1
```

Any help will be great. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that `libmpi.so` is in `/usr/lib64/openmpi`?

Comment: Should it be `/usr/lib64/openmpi/`lib ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After installing `openmpi-devel`,
I see `libmpi.so` in `/usr/lib64/openmpi/lib/`.

```
$ sudo yum install openmpi-devel
$ sudo updatedb
$ locate libmpi.so
/usr/lib64/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so
/usr/lib64/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so.1
/usr/lib64/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so.1.0.2
```

The following should work:

```
install.packages(
  "Rmpi", 
  configure.args = paste( 
    "--with-Rmpi-include=/usr/include/openmpi-x86_64",
    "--with-Rmpi-libpath=/usr/lib64/openmpi/lib",
    "--with-Rmpi-type=OPENMPI"
  )
)
```

If may be necessary to tell the system to look for shared libraries in this directory, as well:

```
# echo "/usr/lib64/openmpi/lib" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/openmpi.conf
# ldconfig
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Vincent. This was for an office setup. We eventually decided to move to Ubuntu for multiple reasons. Anyway, if you can confirm that this works, I'll accept this answer. Thanks.

Comment: I checked on a CentOS virtual machine: after the change to `ld.so.conf`, the package was successfully installed -- but I have not actually used it.